# How to match a character only when a condition is met?

Tags: regex

Say that I have the following string:

```
[AttributeName value1:Foo value2:Bar]
```

AttributeName or valueX aren't important. I can just consider them a sequence of literal or numeric characters.

My question is the following: How can I match `[AttributeName]` as well as

`[AttributeName value1:Foo value2:Bar]`, but not

`[AttributeNamevalue1:Foo value2:Bar]`?
 I am fairly new to Regular Expressions, so a bit of detail on the answers would be really nice.

I tried the following:

```
\[ *[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ *([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\]
```

Which, to my understanding, matches a string that contains a sequence starting with '[', followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, then again 0 or more spaces. The problem comes here.
If I use `*` to match 0 or more spaces, then `[AttributeNamevalue1:Foo value2:Bar]` will be matched. But if I use `+`, then `[AttributeName]` will not be matched since not followed by a space.
How can I perform an if-then-else kind of check? I've found some sources but none of them explained the matter in a beginner-friendly way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\[\s*\w+(\s+\w+:\w+)*\s*\]
```

should work. Here is a code-by-code breakdown:

1. \[\s*\w+(\s+\w+:\w+)*\s*\]
2. \[  Literal opening square bracket
3. \s*  Any white space; may occur zero or more times; longest possible match will be taken
4. \w+  Any word character (A..Z, a..z, _, 0..9); may occur once or more times; longest possible match will be taken
5. (    Begin Group #1
6. \s+ Any white space; may occur once or more times; longest possible match will be taken
7. \w+ Any word character (A..Z, a..z, _, 0..9); may occur once or more times; longest possible match will be taken
8. :   Literal character “:”
9. \w+ Any word character (A..Z, a..z, _, 0..9); may occur once or more times; longest possible match will be taken
10. )   End Group #1
11. *  The entire Group #1 may occur zero or more times; longest possible match will be taken
12. \s* Any white space; may occur zero or more times; longest possible match will be taken
13. \] Literal closing square bracket

(This is output from a utility I wrote for InDesign.)

Comment: Ah, this does it. Thanks a bunch, it really makes the whole thing look less scary.

Comment: Yup. In proper English: basically, it matches a series of *word* characters (whose actual set depends on your GREP dialect, but `[A-Za-z0-9]` is fairly common), then optionally a set of 'space, word, `:`, word', repeated ad infinitum. Spaces before and after your square brackets are optional.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a space to it like:

```
\[([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?:\s+)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\s+))*\]
```

I added a capture group for the AttributeName and a non capturing group for the spaces.